# Handbrake meson configuring fails at "probe: numa" on the Raspberry pi 4

Tags: python, compilation, raspberry-pi, meson-build, handbrake

The configuring of Handbrake (https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake) on my Raspberry pi 4 with the supplied configure file fails because it doesn't find numa.

```
[outeh@outeh-pi HandBrake]$ ./configure 
probe: build tuple...(pass) aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
find: ar...(pass) /usr/bin/ar
find: cp...(pass) /usr/bin/cp
find: gcc...(pass) /usr/bin/gcc
find: gmake...(pass) /usr/bin/make
find: gm4...(pass) /usr/bin/m4
find: meson...(pass) /usr/bin/meson
find: mkdir...(pass) /usr/bin/mkdir
find: ninja-build...(pass) /usr/bin/ninja
find: gpatch...(pass) /usr/bin/patch
find: rm...(pass) /usr/bin/rm
find: ranlib...(pass) /usr/bin/ranlib
find: strip...(pass) /usr/bin/strip
find: gtar...(pass) /usr/bin/tar
find: nasm...(fail) not found
find: autoconf...(pass) /usr/bin/autoconf
find: automake...(pass) /usr/bin/automake
find: cmake...(pass) /usr/bin/cmake
find: libtool...(pass) /usr/bin/libtool
find: pkg-config...(pass) /usr/bin/pkg-config
find: xcodebuild...(fail) not found
find: lipo...(fail) not found
find: python3...(pass) /usr/bin/python3
compute: available architectures...(pass) aarch64
probe: number of CPU cores...(pass) 4
probe: repo info...(pass) https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake.git
compute: project data...(pass) HandBrake (developer)
compute: host tuple...(pass) aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu
probe: numa...(fail) code 1
  : b'Package numa was not found in the pkg-config search path.'
  : b"Perhaps you should add the directory containing `numa.pc'"
  : b'to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable'
  : b"Package 'numa', required by 'virtual:world', not found"
  : [b'conftest.c:2:10: schwerwiegender Fehler: numa.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden', b'    2 | #include <numa.h>', b'      |          ^~~~~~~~', b'Kompilierung beendet.']
ERROR: unable to continue; configure stop.
```

I am using the Raspberry pi 4 version of Manjaro (https://manjaro.org/download/arm/raspebery-pi-4/arm8-raspberry-pi-4-xfce/) my system is updated and I can't find numa in the repos or in the aur.
Handbrake uses the meson buildsystem and all the configure script does is opening this >https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/blob/master/make/configure.py< python script after checking if a python interpreter is present.
Edit:
`echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` returns a blank newline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem on my own, by building libnuma from source.
But I stil don't know why I could not find the appropriate package in the repos.

Answer (score 2):

It means that not all dependencies are installed, in particular, there is at least 
 **libnuma-dev** missing, so you need:

```
sudo apt-get install libnuma-dev
```

or, actually, for your Manjaro:

```
sudo pacman -S libnuma-dev
```

Check [this](https://handbrake.fr/docs/en/latest/developer/install-dependencies-ubuntu.html) for the full list.

Comment: @outeh ok, then check where pkg-config is searching, i.e. can you update your question with contents of PKG_CONFIG_PATH?

Comment: @outeh Here https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/?O=0&SeB=nd&K=numa&outdated=&SB=n&SO=a&PP=50&do_Search=Go by searching with keyword "numa" I found only "lib32-numactl", but you have 64bit arch, so it looks there is no appropriate package in the aur.